# Will the hat be removed if my question is deleted?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015

I earned a hat by posting a question on meta site. Will the hat be removed if the question is deleted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Hats are like badges, once you have them, you have then for good—unless they're removed by an SE employee. Also, I can't find the source right now, but I remember someone (possibly George Stocker) saying that hats will practically never be removed even if the user doesn't deserve the hat. They're temporary, so it's really not worth the effort unless the user would otherwise win the Winter Bash.

Answer (score 5):

No, it is your own and it won't remove if your question/answer is deleted.